# metamask transfer amount different to etherscan amount

Tags: tokens, metamask, transfer

bought a erc-20 token on uniswap using my ledger account on metamask. when i got tokens i transferred them to another account on the same wallet. the amount that appeared was much less that was sent from ledger account. when i check transaction on MM it has correct amount but eth scan has the much less total. EG: bought 1m tokens using ledger linked to MM. Transferred 1m tokens to another account on same MM wallet. Balance now 100,000. where are the other 900,00 tokens?

Comment: share transaction hash, it's impossible to tell without looking at the transaction.